# Cannot run Jhipster app with eclipse. java.lang.LayerInstantiationException:

Tags: java, eclipse, jhipster

I'm trying to use JHipster.
I make a project with start.jhipster.tech. Then, build the project with "mvn clean install" and then try to run the main with eclipse.

The issue: Eclipse can run the application with J2EE but not with spring boot however JHipster is making for it.

The error with spring boot.

```
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor in both module java.base and module jrt.fs
at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.checkSplitPackages(ModuleBootstrap.java:499)
at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(ModuleBootstrap.java:406)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaders(ClassLoader.java:211)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.initialize(Thread.java:430)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:155)
```

The console with j2EE
[image]

Comment: Did you follow the docs? https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse/ As Eclipse is not the most popular IDE in JHipster community, these instructions might need some update.

Comment: Which versions of Java and Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Gael Marizou, thank you. The documentation has the solution. My bad